# Authorize NET ARB generatedTransactions

Tags: authorize.net

I am integrating with Authorize.NET
I have implemented Charge Refund and Automated Recurring Payments

But because recurring payments execute on the Authorize server I need to sync them back. ARB API does not have a QueryTransactions function. Is there any way to implement this functionality in Authorize.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is [Silent Post](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/). It's just like Paypal's IPN in which you are notified whenever a transaction is made and that includes subscription payments made through ARB.

*(Disclaimer: I wrote that article)*